# Se pierde conexión con MYSQL despues de unos minutos con Python y flask

Tags: mysql, python, sql, flask

Tengo mi página subida a pythonanywhere. Cuando hago la conexión y hago clic en "Reload Page" todo funciona normal. Pero despues de unos 15 minutos aproximadamente, deja de conectarse con la base de datos y da un error 500. Se soluciona volviendo a hacerf clic en "Reload Page", pero obvio no es la solución.
Mi código de conexión es:

```
#CONEXIÓN A BASE DE DATOS CON PYMYSQL
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host="miusuario.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com",
    user="miusuario1",
    password="micontraseña",
    db="mi_base_de_datos",
    charset='utf8'
)
#CONEXIÓN A BASE DE DATOS CON PYMYSQL
```

Mi consulta al hago así:

```
@app.route('/demo')
def demo():
    global connection
    cursorsm = connection.cursor()
    select_all="SELECT * FROM mi_tabla ORDER BY precio ASC"
    cursorsm.execute(select_all)
        #ADICIONAL SE PUEDE CONVERTIR EN DICCIONARIO A LOS RESULTADOS
    fetched_all_sm=cursorsm.fetchall()

    cursorsm.close()
    return render_template('demo.html', fetched_all_sm=fetched_all_sm)
```

Esto funciona bien unos minutos y luego se rompe la conexión. ¿Cómo podrái solucionarlo?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buenas, no tienes ningún tipo de archivo log o por terminal que pueda especificar el problema? Puedes intentar con app.run(debug=True) para ver si te indica algo.

Answer (score 1):

es posible que al crear la conexión de forma global, la plataforma la acabe cerrando eventualmente para ahorrar recursos, esto es lo que he encontrado al respecto:

> The error is possibly because you have some code that takes up a connection and doesn't close it. Periodically, those connections are cleared down, which is why it then works for you.

Puedes encontrar el hilo completo [aquí](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12372/).